# Is there a way to sort json object into right groups

Tags: json, typescript

I have the following:

```
{  
    "aGame":"STAR",
    "eleSort":[  
        {  
            "groupId":"mix",
            "groupName":"mixed kind"
        },
        {  
            "groupId":"unmixed",
            "groupName":"unmixed kind"
        }
    ],
    "sortsKind":[  
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_zipcodeext",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":11,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_orgState_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":4,
            "column":1,
            "regex":null,
            "selectValues":[  

                {  
                    "value":"Ohio",
                    "key":"OH"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Oklahoma",
                    "key":"OK"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Oregon",
                    "key":"OR"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Pennsylvania",
                    "key":"PA"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Rhode Island",
                    "key":"RI"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"South Carolina",
                    "key":"SC"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"South Dakota",
                    "key":"SD"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Tennessee",
                    "key":"TN"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Texas",
                    "key":"TX"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Utah",
                    "key":"UT"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Vermont",
                    "key":"VT"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Virginia ",
                    "key":"VA"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Washington",
                    "key":"WA"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"West Virginia",
                    "key":"WV"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Wisconsin",
                    "key":"WI"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Wyoming",
                    "key":"WY"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_orgTINSearchButton",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix"
            ],
            "row":5,
            "column":1,
            "regex":null,
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_tinssn_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":1,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"(([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4}),[ ]*)*([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4})",
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_lbn_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":2,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"(([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4}),[ ]*)*([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4})",
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_tin",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":7,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"(([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4}),[ ]*)*([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_lbn",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":8,
            "column":1
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_certNumber",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ]
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_phonenum",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":10,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
            "validationMsg":"Enter information in valid fomat"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_ext",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":13,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"Numeric *************"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_compfax",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":15,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"XXX-XXX-XXXX Numeric Dash (-) ************",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Enter the information in this field in the correct format."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_faxnumext",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":16,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{0,5}",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry. 2. <Field Name>: Enter the information in this field in the correct format."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_add1",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":14,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"************* ASCII except brackets < or > or ) or ( ***********",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: The required field is missing information. 2. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_add2",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":17,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"************* ASCII except brackets < or > or ) or ( *************",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_orgCity_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":3,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[A-Za-z- '.]+",
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_zipcode",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":12,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{5}",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: The required field is missing information. 2. <Field Name>: Enter the information in this field in the correct format."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_country",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":18,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"Default United States *************",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry."
        }
    ]
}
```

If you read it, you see sortsKind is an array of objects.
In each object inside this array you will find a attribute named attrGroups, which is an array. Some objects have two elements in this array. But I want each object to have only one element in attrGroups array. Meaning, if you see two elements in attrGroups array, I want the whole object to be cloned two times and only have one element inside it. First object has attrGroup of mix, and second object has attrGroup of unmixed. I want to achieve this via a typescript function.

Comment: What have you tried so far? JSON is just a data representation. You'll have to read the JSON into TypeScript/JavaScript objects, then wrangle those objects to match what you want, and then you can convert them to JSON again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
const a = {  
    "aGame":"STAR",
    "eleSort":[  
        {  
            "groupId":"mix",
            "groupName":"mixed kind"
        },
        {  
            "groupId":"unmixed",
            "groupName":"unmixed kind"
        }
    ],
    "sortsKind":[  
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_zipcodeext",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":11,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_orgState_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":4,
            "column":1,
            "regex":null,
            "selectValues":[  

                {  
                    "value":"Ohio",
                    "key":"OH"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Oklahoma",
                    "key":"OK"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Oregon",
                    "key":"OR"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Pennsylvania",
                    "key":"PA"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Rhode Island",
                    "key":"RI"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"South Carolina",
                    "key":"SC"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"South Dakota",
                    "key":"SD"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Tennessee",
                    "key":"TN"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Texas",
                    "key":"TX"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Utah",
                    "key":"UT"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Vermont",
                    "key":"VT"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Virginia ",
                    "key":"VA"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Washington",
                    "key":"WA"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"West Virginia",
                    "key":"WV"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Wisconsin",
                    "key":"WI"
                },
                {  
                    "value":"Wyoming",
                    "key":"WY"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_orgTINSearchButton",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix"
            ],
            "row":5,
            "column":1,
            "regex":null,
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_tinssn_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":1,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"(([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4}),[ ]*)*([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4})",
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_lbn_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":2,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"(([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4}),[ ]*)*([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4})",
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_tin",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":7,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"(([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]{4}),[ ]*)*([EHRSXehsrx9]{1}[0-9]"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_lbn",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":8,
            "column":1
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_certNumber",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ]
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_phonenum",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":10,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
            "validationMsg":"Enter information in valid fomat"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_ext",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":13,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"Numeric *************"
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_compfax",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":15,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"XXX-XXX-XXXX Numeric Dash (-) ************",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Enter the information in this field in the correct format."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_faxnumext",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":16,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{0,5}",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry. 2. <Field Name>: Enter the information in this field in the correct format."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_add1",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":14,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"************* ASCII except brackets < or > or ) or ( ***********",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: The required field is missing information. 2. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_add2",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":17,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"************* ASCII except brackets < or > or ) or ( *************",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_orgCity_si",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "mix",
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":3,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[A-Za-z- '.]+",
            "validationMsg":"1. Your search returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_zipcode",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":12,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"[0-9]{5}",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: The required field is missing information. 2. <Field Name>: Enter the information in this field in the correct format."
        },
        {  
            "sortsKindId":"post_country",
            "attrGroups":[  
                "unmixed"
            ],
            "row":18,
            "column":1,
            "regex":"Default United States *************",
            "validationMsg":"1. <Field Name>: Your entry contains an invalid character. Please re-type your entry."
        }
    ]
} 

const b = a.sortsKind.reduce((sum, val) => {
    val.attrGroups.forEach(element => {
        const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val)); // clone object
        cloned.attrGroups = [element];
        sum.push(cloned);
    });
    return sum;
}, []);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i wanted @Nguyen Phong Thien. Thank you so so much